# clearing div content through php and ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

```
  echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"  src="../play.js">    $("#txtCreatureInfo").remove(); </script>';
```

I am wondering why this id not working.  I have this line in a PhP file and i need it to remove the text inside the div .  I am using ajax and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the text inside the div, you cannot use .remove(). .remove() will delete the element. Instead you should use .html(""). This will clear the text and not remove the div.

So you can write it this way.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#txtCreatureInfo").html("");</script>';
```

Comment: Ive tried that before. I think the problem is with the returning of my php using ajax.
I have a php file with a text box, the java script calls other php files based on the input from the first php file, then executes server commands and returns the outcome to the first php file. the ,empty() command is being returned to the first php file from the second one which runs server commands

Comment: I have play.php, play.js, and attack_creature.php.

Comment: that's odd. I just pasted what you coded and it worked. That is the exact code i used the first time before changing to .empty and .remove. i wonder why it didnt work then.

Thank you!!! (was working on that part for 2 hours)

Comment: That's Great. Maybe their was a minor mistake you were making without realizing. And you happen to fix it unknowingly. Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){ $("#txtCreatureInfo").remove(); })</script>';
```

Need not to mention js here,and also put it on document read or $(function(){----}) and makesure that you will add js files at the header